# Cohomology group homomorphism induced by maps of spheres

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose I have a continuous map $f:S^n \rightarrow S^p \times S^q$, where $n = p+q$. Is it possible to say what the induced homomorphism in cohomology groups $f^{\ast}:H^n(S^p \times S^q;R) \rightarrow H^n(S^n;R)$ has to be for an arbitrary coefficient ring $R$?

I'm not quite sure how to approach answering this. I know that each of the groups here is isomorphic to $R$; the temptation to use cup products to make a conclusion about the cohomology rings, using that we have cohomology ring $H^{\ast}(S^p \times S^q;R) \cong R[\alpha,\beta]/(\alpha^2,\beta^2)$ for $|\alpha| = p$ and $|\beta| = q$, for example, seems to be a more difficult approach than what's needed here.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the cup product! The cohomology of $S^p\times S^q$ has two generators as a ring, and each of those must get mapped to $0$ for degree reasons. (Assuming $p,q<n$.)Hence the induced map must be trivial in degree $n$ as well.